# Checking PCBs for functionality

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

I was wondering, do there exist any service that will check to see if your PCB, based upon a schematic / board layout, will work when built?

**EDIT**
Thank you for all of your answers.   To clarify something, the reason I ask is because I am designing a PCB with no formal electrical engineering experience / education.  I kind of taught myself through it, so I'm a bit nervous to put it together.  I am using SMD components so I can prototype them on a Breadboard.

As far as professional review, are there any sites / services that provide this as I don't know anyone with a background in this area

Comment: There are many ways a design can fail that require specific tools or experience according to design dependency on geometry, thermal, EMI and controlled impedances.  DFM covers a broad range of basics in PCB design, lumped element, design tolerance, margin analysis, timing tolerance stackup,  which are unique skills.  In other words there are many ways to fail, some tools cover some of them.  Mentor tools are many of them at more than $100k/"seat" or workstation.

Comment: search = inurl:.pdf dfm pcb

Comment: Hire an EE consultant, there are numerous places to find people like that. We don't do product recommendations here because they are off topic

Comment: Get some breakout PCBs that adapt your SMD components to fit in a breadboard. Then prototype on a breadboard.

Answer (score 2):

In general no.

Spice is ok for simple electrical issues, but is only ever as good as the parasitics you include in your model, including your model of the board layout (And by the time you put all that in, it often stops converging)!

IME most of the issues with first prototypes are some combination of footprint/symbol problems and simple thinkos.

By far the best approach is to get someone else experienced to spend a day going over the thing. First the schematics before you start in on the layout, and then the layout paying particular attention to any new symbols or footprints. 
You can of course pay for someone to do this, but that sort of review will never catch everything.

One thing I will often do if review is not practical is to send out a board as soon as placement is complete so I can do a physical check of the footprints and such, I can get this back in a few ways and as it only includes the top and bottom layers it is cheap. This is also useful for the mechanical guys to check assembly details.

Some of the board houses have on line DFM tools that will catch some board level issues (Uneven copper distribution, min T/G, annual ring and via sizes for example), but that says nothing about the electrical functionality.

Answer (score 1):

That's what ***Spice software*** is used for. Spice software allow you to look at the performance of the circuit. As far as building a PCB, you import the circuit your built in the Spice software and import it to the PCB building software (i.e. National Instruments has a Spice simulator called "Multisim" and you can import that schematic to "Ultiboard" which is a PCB layout software).

Answer (score 0):

If you know your PCB files are good, you can ask the manufacturer for e-test. This uses flying probes to check that the manufactured PCB corresponds to your files. For example, it will detect broken tracks, shorts, etc. Then, you can be pretty sure your PCBs are good and you're not gonna waste components on a bad board.

Now, if you want to know whether your layout is good, what you need is a pro layout engineer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Matching a design to written requirements is non-trivial. More and more, EDA tools will find and flag trivial errors such as floating inputs and shorts on the PCB but there are still almost infinite ways a design may fail to meet requirements (assuming the requirements are adequate in the first place). If you mis-read a drawing and make the wrong footprint then the part won't fit properly, for example, and the EDA tools won't necessarily save you (but printing out the copper and placing new (to you) parts on top of it might). There are other tricks, like 'walking' through a netlist and eyeballing what goes where. Double and triple check the schematic, give nets sensible names, and so on. Simulate and perhaps breadboard small portions of the circuit that are tricky.

Usually companies will have design reviews and get more eyes on the problem. A method the sole practitioner can use is to finish the design early and set it aside for some days, returning to it with fresh eyes. You could also try presenting your design to a spouse or even to a rubber duck and explaining the details of your approach.

Another approach is the "fail early, fail often" one- get your prototype out fast and make it good but perhaps not perfect, then iterate. Once you have a bit of experience it's rare that a board will be unusable.